# How to write data to InfluxDB form a streaming API directly through curl request or any other way

Tags: streaming, influxdb, grafana

I have created a Web API (prototype) which can provide me artificial streaming data. This API send two data points/second as response.
**[Click to see the response image here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tT1S2.png)**

Now I need to write those data points (provided by API) to "InfluxDB" directly from the API.

I have tried a lot but unable to find any way to save my web API response (those artificial data points) in INFLUXDB. Please suggest how to do it or if there is any other way to save data in INFLUXDB from API.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be as simple as making an HTTP `POST` request to the `/write` endpoint of your InfluxDB instance with two query parameters specified `db` and `precision`. For additional information see the [writing data](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.13/guides/writing_data/) documentation.